# Vault: how to create an secret-id

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've created a token:

```
$ vault token lookup abac979c-d00d-4182-5654-793861dc0be9
Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            ee63d369-0823-4f5d-62c3-5fb877f36a36
creation_time       1529483637
creation_ttl        604800
display_name        token
entity_id           n/a
expire_time         2018-06-27T08:33:57.103907674Z
explicit_max_ttl    0
id                  abac979c-d00d-4182-5654-793861dc0be9
issue_time          2018-06-20T08:33:57.103907333Z
meta                <nil>
num_uses            0
orphan              false
path                auth/token/create
policies            [default openshift-token-manager]
renewable           true
ttl                 603405
```

As you can see it has `openshift-token-manager` policy. This policy looks like:

```
vault policy read openshift-token-manager
path "auth/approle/role/openshift/secret-id" {
    capabilities = ["update"]
}
```

I'm using this token in order to create a `secret-id`:

```
$ vault write -f auth/approle/role/openshift-ro/secret-id
Error writing data to auth/approle/role/openshift-ro/secret-id: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://vault.vault-sidekick.svc/v1/auth/approle/role/openshift-ro/secret-id
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role **openshift-ro** that you are trying to create a secret-id for doesn't match the role granted in your policy, **openshift** - so the permission denied error seems correct based on that.

Change your policy to grant access to the **openshift-ro** role.